# Knockout.js: Sort on multiple keys

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js

In Knockout.js, is it possible to sort by *multiple* keys?

For example:

```
var anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray([
{ name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
{ name: "Boogle", type: "Bear" },
{ name: "George", type: "Hippo" },
{ name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }
]);
```

For example, I might want to sort ASC by `type` first, and then by DESC `name`. Is this possible with KO observable arrays?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually extend my observable arrays with this `sortBy` method that lets me define the field to sort by as well as the sorting direction:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.sortBy = function(fld, direction)
{
    var isDesc = direction && direction.toLowerCase() == 'desc';

    return ko.observableArray(this.sort(function (a, b) {
        a = ko.unwrap(a[fld]);
        b = ko.unwrap(b[fld]);

        return (a == b ? 0 : a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isDesc ? -1 : 1);
        }));
};
```

Then when binding:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: yourArray.sortBy('type', 'asc')">
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u159jyn0/5/)

Comment: Interesting approach. However, this does not do a "ThenBy" sort. Instead, it first sorts on 'type', and after that it **re-sorts the entire array** by 'name'. See [this updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwLL8ks6/) for the problem.

Comment: True, that's why I didn't name it `thenBy`. But seems like it did get the OP where he wanted.

Answer (score 2):

An observable array is just that: an array that is observable. Arrays are as they are: in a specific order. If you either add the items ordered, or sort the array to reshuffle it it'll be ordered.

Have a look at the [observable array documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html): they support most array functions, including sorting. A [`sort` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) takes a comparison function as an argument. In this function you can compare as you like, on as many properties as you desire.

E.g.:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" },
    { name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
    { name: "Boogle", type: "Bear" },
    { name: "George", type: "Hippo" }
  ]);

  self.anotherObservableArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameResult = a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    
    if (nameResult === 0) {
      return a.type.localeCompare(b.type);
    }
    
    return nameResult;
  });
  
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: anotherObservableArray">
  <li data-bind="text: name + ' ' + type"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. This works, too. I selected haim770's because of the method chaining example. Would up vote but for my rep.

Comment: @FurryThoughts That's ok, you're welcome to accept whichever answer you prefer. I do like the idea of a chained syntax, though it'd need some tweaking to make it work (I left a comment at the other answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may implement you own [sorting function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html). Not sure this is exactly the same sorting you want, something similar at least.

```
anotherObservableArray.sort(function(left, right) 
{ 
  return left.name== right.name ? 0 : (left.type< right.type? -1 : 1) 
});
```